# "As shocking as Steven Avery’s case is to Netflix viewers"

Tags: syntax

As shocking as Steven Avery’s case is to Netflix viewers, his wrongful imprisonment for 18 years is not an isolated incident in the troubled US criminal justice system.

http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2016/apr/26/making-a-murderer-attorneys-poverty-wrongful-convictions

I am a little bit confused by phrasing of the above sentence. It sems to me as two separate parts which do not fit together. The first part is interrupted by the comma. Why? I would understand if this sentence would have this form: *As shocking as Steven Avery’s case is to Netflix viewers the fact that his wrongful imprisonment for 18 years is not an isolated incident in the troubled US criminal justice system*. Do you find the sentence structure of the sentence OK?

P. S. Is in "to Netflix viewers" the correct preposition used? I would await "for".

Comment: Why do you think the comma is not required. What role do you think the first "as" is playing there?

Comment: Steven Avery’s case is to/for Neflix viewers shocking because it reflects the more general problem in the american justice. By this way I would paraphrase the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I don't think it's saying that it's shocking *because* it reflects a general problem; it's essential saying that it's shocking and you might not realize this is not an isolated incident.

Comment: Although it is shocking, it is hardly uncommon.  Concession clause.  Also, **to** is the correct preposition. It is shocking to them = it seems shocking to them.

Comment: It did not come to me that this is a Concession clause. The part "as shocking as" completly confused me. I translated it in the similar way as "as much as" and so on.

Comment: As confused as you were, now you understand. i.e. although you were quite confused...

Comment: As hot and sticky as Houston is, I'll take it over Siberia any day.

Comment: To tell the truth I have not found the structure "as adjective as" as the structure introducing the concession clause. I have known so far that "as…as" functions as the comparative.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "**have** not found".  Do you mean to say "**had** not found", or are you disagreeing with my explanation?

Comment: I do not have any reason to question your answer and thank you for your help. I just wanted to tell that the structure "as…as" functioning as here was explained is for me surprising discovery. By using "have not found" I only meant that I have not been able to find this grammar matter either in my grammar books or in the internet. But that is my problem. Just one question: does this structure is limited to the pattern "so adjective as + to be"?

Comment: Grammar books might call it a concessive adjunct.

Comment: No, not only **be**, though the underlying idea is a predicate.   As fast as they go, I'd prefer a family stationwagon to a Ferrari.  Although I enjoy speed (or although one might think speed would be a selling point), I would prefer a stationwagon to a Ferrari.

Comment: See pages 2-3 here. http://web.khu.ac.kr/~jongbok/research/final-papers/concessive.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. BTW: your sentence "As hot and sticky as Houston is, I'll take it over Siberia any day". May be I am a bit slow on the uptake but I do not understand it. Is it some sort of joke? Although it is hot in Boston, I will any day ruled Siberia…

Comment: It was an exaggeration, by someone who happens to dislike excessive  heat and humidity, but will take it over double-digit subzero temperatures.